# Idea & kotlin, code auto-completion on lambda parameters

Tags: lambda, parameters, kotlin

I have this `functionalInterface` in lwjgl java so defined:

```
@FunctionalInterface
@NativeType("GLFWkeyfun")
public interface GLFWKeyCallbackI extends CallbackI.V {

    String SIGNATURE = "(piiii)v";

    @Override
    default String getSignature() { return SIGNATURE; }

    @Override
    default void callback(long args) {
        invoke(
            dcbArgPointer(args),
            dcbArgInt(args),
            dcbArgInt(args),
            dcbArgInt(args),
            dcbArgInt(args)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Will be called when a key is pressed, repeated or released.
     *
     * @param window   the window that received the event
     * @param key      the keyboard key that was pressed or released
     * @param scancode the system-specific scancode of the key
     * @param action   the key action. One of:<br><table><tr><td>{@link GLFW#GLFW_PRESS PRESS}</td><td>{@link GLFW#GLFW_RELEASE RELEASE}</td><td>{@link GLFW#GLFW_REPEAT REPEAT}</td></tr></table>
     * @param mods     bitfield describing which modifiers keys were held down
     */
    void invoke(@NativeType("GLFWwindow *") long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);

}
```

And I have a corresponding kotlin:

`typealias KeyCallbackT = (key: Int, scanCode: Int, action: Int, mods: Int) -> Unit`

The big thing I'm missing (and which bothers me since it's very error prone), it's that whenever I start typing `GLFWKeyCallbackI` then I can choose the corresponding code auto-completion option that will automatically write all the defined parameters:

`GLFWKeyCallbackI { window, key, scanCode, action, mods ->`

Like this:

[image: Imgur]

But I don't have the same on kotlin with my `typealias`

I have, of course, multiple other similar situations and it'd be nice if I could get the same auto-completion